# set rails root in environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

i'm deploying my app to a shared hosting environment, and apparently i need to set up the root path in my environment file. when i try to boot it up i get this error:

** Starting Rails with production environment...
/home/donner/etc/rails_apps/donnerparty/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:902:in `read': No such file or directory

i can't find any clear instructions on how to set the root path.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your config/routes.rb a line similar to the one below, adapted to your appropriate needs.

```
root :to => 'store#index', :as => 'store'
```

There is also an already commented out line in config.rb

```
root :to => "welcome#index"
```

don't forget to delete the file public/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You likely want something like this in your environments/production.rb file (unless you are testing and developing in the same place - then you want it just in the general environment.rb):

RAILS_ROOT = /home/donner/etc/rails_apps/donnerparty